# How do I call the right controller function in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a button, and when I click on that button, it will being me to `user/create`. I'm clueless trying to debug why my `show()` function is executing rather than my create function.

[image]

## Route

```
// Auth Group 
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

    //Users
    Route::get('user/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'UserController@show'));
   
});
```

---

```
// Auth and Admin Group 
$router->group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function() {

    Route::get('user/create', array('as'=>'user.create', 'uses'=>'UserController@create'));
    
});
```

Obviously, I set `user/create` to call the **create** function.

---

## UserController

**Show** - I have no idea why this function get executed.

```
public function show($id)
{
    dd("I'm inside the show function ");

    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return View::make('users.show')
        ->with('user', $user);
}
```

---

**Create** - suppose to call this function

```
// Bring up create form for Aveniros user
public function create(){
    return View::make('users.create');
}
```

---

Does anybody know why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `/user/create` matches the route `Route::get('user/{id}', array());`
You can add a costraint to user `id` so that only integers will be matched:

```
Route::get('user/{id}', array(
    'before' =>'profile', 
    'uses'=>'UserController@show'
))->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Also you can interchange the order of your routes so that `Route::get('/user/create')` will be matched FIRST.

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing.. this is actually a specific example covered in the Laracasts on Laravel 5. Yes, put the route for the non-wildcard task (/create) before the wildcard ({id}) otherwise ({id}) handles everything and it never gets to /create.